# zsh alias - command not found: "open or "cd

Tags: zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

While trying to create aliases in zsh, I end up getting a response of

```
zsh: command not found: “open
```

from the alias in .zshrc

```
alias plex=“open -a Plex\ Media\ Server”
```

Using single quotes gives the same output. Does anyone know why this is or how to deal with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes?

Comment: For some reason textedit was changing them, even after pasting directly from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't standard double quotes. Look closely:

```
“
"
```

The former is yours. The latter is correct.

What are you using to edit your .zshrc?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I ever would've caught that.  I've been using macOS textedit

Comment: @m00nby If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept.